# access a control from another in winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, tabcontrol

What is wrong with this code? I want to change a label in Form1 in tabControl1 in tabPage3.

```
private void FormInsertDanaScores_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    Form1 frm = new Form1();
    foreach (Control c in frm.Controls)
    {
        foreach (TabPage TabPage in tabControl1.TabPages)
        {
            foreach (Control control in TabPage.Controls)
            {
                if (control.Name == "lblInsertEditScores")
                {
                    
                    ((Label)(c)).BackColor = Color.Transparent;
                    ((Label)(c)).Text = "jjjjjj";
                    frm.Refresh();
                }
            }
           
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Is "lblInsertEditScores" in the same form, or a different form than where the posted code is running?

Comment: From the comments below, this form was shown via `ShowDialog()`.  That means code has STOPPED in Form1.  All you need to do is access the label, from Form1 itself, AFTER the `ShowDialog()` call: `Form2.ShowDialog();`  --> `this.lblInsertEditScores.BackColor = Color.Transparent;`  There's no need to do this from the other form...

Answer (score 3):

The line that reads `Form1 frm = new Form1();` is your problem.  You are generating an entirely new version of the form, and changing the label on that new form.  Instead, try and store a reference to the form you want to change, or get at it as a parent of the current control perhaps.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looping over all labels and checking the name, you would probably change the accessibility of the affected label and make it `public` for example. Your code is then as simple as

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
from.lblInsertEditScores.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
from.lblInsertEditScores.Text = "jjjjjj";
```

The next thing is that `new` creates a new object, that is a new window. But you never show that new window. My guess is that you have such a window already and you don't want to create another one. So instead of creating a new one, you should use the already existing one.

So in `FormInsertDanaScores` create a new property like

```
public Form1 frm;
```

and assign that after you created `FormInsertDanaScores`. You didn't show that code, but it may look like

```
Form1 frm = new Form1();
frm.Show();

var danaScores = new FormInsertDanaScores();
danaScores.frm = frm;
danaScores.Show();
```

The naming is far from perfect, BTW. `Form1` is a bad class name and `frm` is too generic as well. Those names should express something meaningful.

If Form1 is already open and you show the additional window from inside Form1, your code might look like this:

```
var danaScores = new FormInsertDanaScores();
danaScores.frm = this;
danaScores.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: form 1 is already open and not hidden and form2 that is "FormInsertDanaScores" is shown via         FormInsertDanaScores Form2 = new FormInsertDanaScores();
        Form2.ShowDialog();

Comment: @bahadorarghavan: I've added another example which probably matches your scenario better.